# How to get a date time object in UTC that is the last time it was a certain time

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime

I need to make sure if its after 21 hours in UTC or 4 pm est to set the initial day in the date picker as the next day although i need help with the logic of getting a date time object of the last time when it was last 21 hours in UTC.

For example if its 22 hours in utc the last time it was 21 hours was a hour ago so i just use the same utc date and subtract a hour

although a couple hours after it will be a new utc date how do i represent that? Does any one have any ideas?

Im using datetime and using custom color picker libraries is not the solution i'm interested in. I just need help on the logic of how to set Initial date/ Current date in my custom calendar picker with the criteria that after 21 hours utc it should move to the next day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to test the UTC hour, which is returned by *getUTCHours*, so:

```js
function getDate(date = new Date()) {
  // Copy date so don't affect original
  let d = new Date(date);
  // If 2100 UTC or later, set to tomorrow UTC
  if (d.getUTCHours() > 20) {
    d.setUTCDate(d.getUTCDate() + 1);
  }
  // Set the time to 2100
  d.setUTCHours(21,0,0,0);
  return d;
}

// Current value
console.log(getDate());

// Value for 2021-03-01T22:00:00Z
console.log(getDate(new Date(Date.UTC(2021,2,1,22)))); // T21:00:00.000Z
```